# Getting null in front end when sending data from backend app script

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am trying to get single row in object format but dont know why always getting null in front end. Where backend functing giving me correct output.

This is the output i am getting in console in backend appscript

[image]

This is main function that giving me output

[image]

This is the function in front end i am getting null here
[image]

Comment: Please show the codes instead of images

Comment: Please visit the [help], take the [tour] to see what and [ask]. If you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output using the `[<>]` [snippet editor](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do).

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `getValues`, use `getDisplayValues()`, this is will return date as string, which is the cause of getting null in `client side` as date is prohibited.

**Reference:-**

[Parameters and Return Values](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/communication#parameters_and_return_values)